# Delete or remove dashed frame around my UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i have this UIVIew with label text that says welcome who ever login the system:
[image]

i have mentioned that in new iphones (lets say from iphone xs and above) i have this issue:
[image]

as you can see, the frame is getting over the iphone time clock and the signal.
now i took aside the uiview and saw a dashed frame like this:
[image]

even if i make the view it self a bit smaller, i still see the dashed line around, like this:
[image]

can anyone know what can be the issue?

Comment: In your third picture, next to ```View``` is a little white arrow inside an orange circle. If you click on that, it might give you options to fix this problem.

Comment: the arrow is there because i wanted to show you the issue so i moved the view aside so you can still see the dashed frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dashed lines" indicate that your view (or other UI elements) have been moved and do not match the constraints you've setup.

For example, I've given this label Top / Leading / Trailing constraints to the safe-area, and a Height constraint of 46:

[image]

If I then drag the label down a little bit:

[image]

I get the orange dashed lines and little number (obscured by the sizing handle) indicating it is out of position.

When you see that, you should also see that this button becomes active:

[image]

Hovering over that button shows the tool-tip: "Update Frames" ... clicking it will move your out-of-place view(s) back to where they should be, based on the constraints you've assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to constraint your view with a label to the safe are top anchor then you are going to see a a background color of the view controller view above the view.

To solve it you have to create a view which has the same color as your view with a label and constraint it's top anchor to the super view top anchor and it's bottom anchor to the bottom anchor of the view with label. This solution will display the view with label background color in Safe Area top zone on devices with notch and without it and keep your view with label height constant across different devices

[image]

[image]